# VBA Named Range in Excel Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to add a range:

```
Combined_Data.Range("A1:AZ200").Find("Marker").Offset(1,0).Select  
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select  
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Marker",RefersTo:=Selection
```

When I use the named range "Marker" in an excel formula (typed directly into the spreadsheet), the workbook doesn't seem to respect the values contained in the range. The only way I can get it to work is to use an R1C1 reference to the cells I want in the range.

Does anyone know how I can avoid the specific cell reference?

When I look at the Name Manager, the actual cell references of the range are correct. In this example it is: A6:A1655. The Name Manager has: ='Combined Data'!$A$6:$A$1655

When I use the R1C1 reference, the range appears the same in the Name Manager.

Comment: How have you declared/defined `Combined_Data`?

Comment: Please give and example of _use the named range "Marker" in an excel formula_ that gives the wrong results (create and post a _small_ data set and expected and actual results)

Comment: Combined_Data is the name of a worksheet.

=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Amount,Payor_Name,D$7,Marker,$B$8,Bill_Area_Data,Report_BillArea,Post_Date,Rpt_Month,Encounter_Type, Encounter_Type_Selection))

As you can see, I have several named ranges, and I am defining them all the same way (Using the code originally posted).

Comment: The formula does not error out, it just doesn't return anything. When I add the same ranges manually using the Name Manager or with a R1C1 reference in VBA, the formula returns values.

Answer (score 1):

All the ranges should be fully qualified to the same worksheet `Combined_Data`.  You also need to set the `Range.Find()` `After` parameter to the first cell in the Range.

```
Dim marker As Range

With Combined_Data
    Set marker = .Range("A1:AZ200").Find("Marker", After:=.Range("A1"))
    If Not marker Is Nothing Then
        Set marker = marker.Offset(1, 0)
        Set marker = .Range(marker, marker.End(xlDown))
        marker.Name = "Marker"
    End If
End With
```

These videos will help: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) and [Excel VBA Introduction Part 15a - Find and FindNext](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=_ZVSV9Y7TGw&index=17&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: What does it mean for a range to be "fully qualified"?

Comment: `Range()` is unqualified because it refers to cells on the default Worksheet.  `Fully Qualified` refers to a range that is implicitly set to a Worksheet, (e.g.  `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range()`).  When dealing with multiple Workbooks the Worksheet should be `Fully Qualified` to a Workbook, `Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range()`).  This will ensure that you are always working with the intended Range.

Comment: Cells and Ranges inside a range should also be qualified to the same Worksheet.  The best way to do that is to use a With Statement.  In some case it is advantages to set a Worksheet variable. `Set ws = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1")`,   `Range(ws.Range(),ws.Range())`, `ws.Range(ws.Range(),ws.Range())`, `ws.Range(ws.Range(),ws.Cells())`,

Comment: The suggested code worked, but why didn't my code work given that the ranges were listed in the Name Manager with the correct name and cell references?

Comment: @PhillipKreighbaum The worksheet formula should update with the named range.  I don't know why it wouldn't, if you are 100% sure that the named range is correct.  I had thought that your named range may have been off due to not setting the first cell used by `Range.Find()`.